# IT Support mySQL Database structure

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a ticket system for issues regarding IT.  I have the following table:

```
id                          
userID                                  
priority                                        
details                              
rank                                
conversation                                
order                                   
status                                  
ts
```

What I need is to be able to display the back and forth between the IT dept and the user as a conversation.  So i figure I have the two columns `conversation` and `order`.  The column `conversation` would be a unique identifier (number or text) and the order would show the order that the row plays in the converstation (1,2,3 etc).

My question is this:

1. Is this the best way to go about it?
2. how shall I identify each conversation?

I could either generate random PHP 5 char text or something, or give a number, and each user has conversation number 1, number 2 etc.  But then If I did that, how would I find out the next number to use for the user using mySQL?

Any thoughts and suggestions would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a separate table like @Debock mentioned. I'd structure it a bit differently though:

```
create table ticket_conversation (
    id                     int not null auto_increment primary key
,   ticket_id              int not null
,   user_id                int not null
,   conversation_text      text
,   conversation_timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp
,   foreign key ticket_id references ticket(id) 
,   foreign key user_id references user(id)
,   key(ticked_id, conversation_timestamp)
)
```

The timestamp allows you to keep track of when the comment was made, and ordering by it will give you the sequence of comments.

Comment: Aha, ordering by timestamp does make alot of sense.  And I used to joining tables via JOIN in my SQL, however I dont think I have set up a table that has a set foreign key, I wonder if phpMyAdmin can do that?

Comment: Found the relation view.  Thanks, I think i'll give this ago, It makes alot of sense.

Comment: @Chud37 you can join tables regardless of the presence of a foreign key constraint. The purpose of the foreign key constraint is to ensure no "orphan" comments can be added. Ie foreign keys are an integrity feature, the do not change the way you can query your database. I added the foreign key constraints in my code to explain how to use the columns. it's up to you if you want to copy that design verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably store the conversation in a different table with a unique id and link that id in the ticket table.

This other table could consist out of an auto increment id for the sequence of the "back and forth", the global conversation key (stored in your ticket table) and the conversation(line) itself of course.

I would also suggest you store the username of the support tech as well as the supportee so that it remains clear who said what.

You could add timestamps for clarity as well.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables usually have a column that stores a unique identifier called a primary key.  The primary key can be an auto-generated integer.  So you don't need to fuss about trying to create unique identifiers in PHP.

I would suggest that some intense reading about databases and how they work should be in your near future.  Try [Database Design for Mere Mortals](http://www.amazon.ca/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Relational/dp/0201694719). It will give you a good grounding both on what's possible and on how to approach problems from a db design viewpoint.

Comment: Okay I understand about primary keys etc, So then If I need to be able to select from the table all tickets from <user> that are in a specific <conversation> how would I do that with just the <id> field? I'd need to know all of the <id> fields in order to select them and return them.

Comment: When you create a conversation, you fetch the conversation id with last_insert_id().  Then, when you want all the posts in a conversation, you `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE conversation_id = x`.